# Vector and for doesn't produce results

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, runtime-error, abort

I'm working on a simple game (rock, paper, scissors) and I got this problem when I try to populate a vector with using elements of another vector as conditions. The code maybe is more easy to understand:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "../../Library/std_lib_facilities.h"

// With the fibonacci series I can generate a secret sequence of number
int fib(int n){
    if (1 == n || 2 == n) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    }
}

// It shows the list of element in a given vector
void showVector(vector<int>myVector, string nameVector) {
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << nameVector << " Debug: | ";
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << myVector[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
}

// String variant
void showVector(vector<string>myVector, string nameVector) {
    cout << "\n\n";
    cout << nameVector << " Debug: | ";
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << myVector[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << "\n\n";
}

// Generate a sequence of number in a vector
vector<int> generateCode(int input) {

    vector<int>myVector;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        myVector.push_back(fib(i + input) % 3);
    }

    return myVector;
}

int main()
{
    // Secret sequence of moves, based on the value (0, 1 or 2) i will show Rock, Paper or Scissor
    vector<int>fibSeries;
    vector<string>movSeries;

    // Initialization and settings
    int input = 0;

    cout << "Digit an integer to start: ";
    while (cin >> input) {

        // Check the number to make sure is a valid one (i will implement a check later) and generate the secret code
        fibSeries = generateCode(input);

        // For each 0 i'll put Rock in the vector, same for 1 ( in this case paper ) and 2 ( scissor )
        for (int i = 0; i <= fibSeries.size(); i++) {
            if (fibSeries[i] == 0){
                movSeries.push_back("Rock");
            }
            else if (fibSeries[i] == 1) {
                movSeries.push_back("Paper");
            }
            else if (fibSeries[i] == 2) {
                movSeries.push_back("Scissor");
            }
            else {
                movSeries.push_back("Rock");
            }
        }

        // Shows the vector graphically, for debug.
        showVector(fibSeries, "fibisSeries");
        showVector(movSeries, "movSeries");

        // So for a combination of      1 - 2 - 0 - 1
        // The result should be:        Paper - Scissor - Rock - Paper

    }

    return 0;
}
```

After i execute the code, i get an (Abort). I don't understand, I'm new to C++ so please forgive me if is a stupid error. And most of the code is complex becouse I have rules to follow, so for example if I didn't study something i can't use it here. I just want to know why the code don't want me to use the for with the vector!

Comment: Your error is here `for (int i = 0; i <= fibSeries.size(); i++)`

Comment: I'm also afraid you'd get stack overflows (the irony) when user input is too high.

Comment: Classic fence post error. `i <= fibSeries.size()`-> `i < fibSeries.size()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for (int i = 0; i <= fibSeries.size(); i++)

As @Yola mentions, you iterate one element more than you have:

if you have the vector `std::vector<char> v = {'a', 'b', 'c'};`, the elements can be accessed as:

```
v[0] (-> 'a')
v[1] (-> 'b')
v[2] (-> 'c')
```

As a rule, your max index will be `length - 1`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= fibSeries.size(); i++)
```

iterates from 0 to less then **or equal** to size(); that is, 0, 1, 2, 3 (4 elements, in a 3 elements vector).

Correct code should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fibSeries.size(); i++)
                 ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

So as has already been stated, your problem is that you should always use `< size` because indexing is [0-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) `<= size` will read off the end of allocated space.

---

But a couple comments if I may, [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) introduced a new style of [range based `for`-loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which will save you from having to write the condition and iteration expressions at all:

```
map<int, string> movSeries = { { 0, "Rock"s }, { 1, "Paper"s }, { 2, "Scissors"s } };
vector<int> fibSeries(10);
auto input = 0;

while(cin >> input) {
    for(auto& i : fibSeries) {
        i = fib(input++) % 3;
    }

    cout << "\n\nDebug | ";
    copy(cbegin(fibSeries), cend(fibSeries), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " | "));
    cout << "\n\n\n\nDebug | ";

    for(const auto i : fibSeries) {
        cout << movSeries[i] << " | ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```